# Nginx - What precautions need to be taken when I turn underscores_in_headers on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm writing a rails application and passing in a custom access token through the HTTP headers.  To accommodate this I need to turn on underscores_in_header in nginx.conf for my code to run. (See [Rails Not able to access headers after moving to Digital Ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245270/rails-not-able-to-access-headers-after-moving-to-digital-ocean))

Because this option is by default off, I assume there are some security risks I assume by turning it on.  However, I have been unable to find an explanation for what these risks or concerns are.  What are these risks and how do I account for them within my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Nginx Pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls)...

> This is done in order to prevent ambiguities when mapping headers to CGI variables, as both dashes and underscores are mapped to underscores during that process.

So it looks like a question of avoiding collisions between variable names. FWIW, the applicable [RFC 7230, sec 3.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6) specifically allows underscores and [RFC 3875, sec. 4.1.18](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.18) states that:

> The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has all occurrences of "-" replaced with "_" and has "HTTP_" prepended to give the meta-variable name.

The security problem, then, is related to this conversion process of "-" to "_" and how receiving applications then access the User-Agent variable. For instance, "User-Agent" would be mapped to "User_Agent" by the server, and then in PHP (for example) the CGI environment var is accessed as:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

In rails:

```
request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

So what happens if the client sends "User_Agent" instead of "User-Agent?" The underscore would be left in place and then "HTTP_USER_AGENT" will have been explicitly set by the a client script (normally, it's set by the browser). The following post from 2007 discusses the potential to exploit this process:

[Exploiting reflected XSS vulnerabilities, where user input must come through HTTP Request Headers](http://kuza55.blogspot.com/2007/07/exploiting-reflected-xss.html)

That post suggests there is a problem if the server app "insecurely prints" the header value (to the client browser) and in the example it would presumably execute a javascript alert popup. It's just an example though.

The question is, does the problem still exist? Well, yes. See the following post that discusses the Shellshock vulnerability where the same idea is used to exploit the BASH shell:

[Inside Shellshock: How hackers are using it to exploit systems](http://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/)

Therefore, if you intend to parse any header with an older version of BASH, you need to be aware of the vulnerability presented by Shellshock. At the end of the day, you should always take care to sanitize any data value that has been sent to your application outside of your control.